# "The male pheasant is brightly colored" VS "A male pheasant is brightly colored" — When to use "the male" and when to use "a male"?

Tags: difference, articles

[britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/pheasant):
**(1)** ***The** male pheasant is brightly colored and **the** female is mostly brown*.

I don't understand why "the" can be used here.

my variant:
**(2)** ***A** male pheasant is brightly colored and **a** female is mostly brown*.

What is the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: When talking about a particular species, it's usual to say _the male, the female, the juvenile'_ (of that species).

Comment: Prefer "Male pheasants are ..."

Answer (score 0):

That use of "the" is used in formal English. Yours is grammatical but not formal.

- **The male pheasant** is brightly colored and the female is mostly brown.
- **The car of the future** will be electric.
- **The bed** was crucial in Western history.
- **The arrowhead** was an early manmade tool.

The the determiner is used *for a category of object or animal*. The same meaning is given by using a plural: Males pheasants are brightly colored. Cars of the future will be electric. This use of *the* to designate a category is common in formal journalistic writing and in academic writing.

Comment: You said "Yours is grammatical but not formal". Therefore, all your examples would also be grammatical but not formal with "a": _a car of the future will be electric_; _a bed was crucial in Western history_; _an arrowhead was an early manmade tool_. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @Loviii Yes, that's right. BUT "a car of the future will be electric" means there will be one car that is or it is a prediction. The second means: A bed [not some x] was crucial in Western history and three is just a definition.

Comment: Can I infer that: "_A car of the future will be electric_" — we're talking about one car. "_A bed was crucial in Western history_" — we're talking about one bed. "_An arrowhead was an early manmade tool_" — we're talking not about one arrowhead but about all arrowheads.

Comment: Yes, to all of those. One caveat: One car **as in** one make of car.

Answer (score 0):

In old-fashioned formal language, when discussing a category of things in general, the definite article and singular is used. In my experience this is only really found in very formal writing these days, and it would be surprising to hear it in speech.

More typically in modern language, the plural is used with no article at all. This generally emphasises the unity of the category.

Using the indefinite article and singular (your suggested alternative) is also possible. This generally emphasises the individual examples of the category.

That leaves the following options, all of which are valid and mean (broadly) the same thing.

Formal, old-fashioned:

- **The male pheasant** is brightly colored and **the female** is mostly brown.

Modern:

- **Male pheasants** are brightly colored and **females** are mostly brown.

Alternative modern:

- **A male pheasant** is brightly colored and **a female** is mostly brown.

Comment: I don't think old fashioned is accurate. It is merely formal. You might not hear it in speech but you might very well hear it in **a** speech.

Comment: @Lambie there may be dialectal differences here, or we have very different definitions of old-fashioned. To me (29yo Southern English) it sounds _extremely_ old fashioned, bordering on archaic. I can't imagine hearing it from anyone below pension age saying it and not having it sound like an affectation. It conjures images of Victorian and Edwardian men wearing tweed. Even from pensioners in formal settings I'd find it marked compared to the other options.

Comment: It is used all the time in academic writing and formal jornalistic writing.

Comment: We also use the definite article:

to say something about all the things referred to by a noun:
The wolf is not really a dangerous animal. (= Wolves are not really dangerous animals.)
The kangaroo is found only in Australia. (= Kangaroos are found only in Australia.)
The heart pumps blood around the body. (= Hearts pump blood around bodies.) https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/definite-article

Comment: @Lambie only the last of those doesn't sound very old-fashioned to me. The former wouldn't sound too out of place for someone like David Attenborough (who's 92), but would sound bizarrely old-fashioned to me in the voice of basically anyone younger than him

Comment: We are not talking about speech per se. It's about **writing it**. Anyway,

Comment: it is interesting though that to me "hearts punp blood around bodies" is strongly disprefered (likewise other instances of components, e.g. "the nucleus is where the DNA is stored in the cell" is fine, but "nuclei are where DNA is stored in cells" sounds weird)

Comment: @Lambie sure. In writing it would also still seem old-fashioned to me. Significantly less than in speech, but it is still how it would seem to me

Comment: I don't think the British Council uses old-fashioned English, unless they say so. The heart pumps blood [etc.] is found on tons of sites. You have to sign in but there are also tons of "the electric car as a category" on ludwig.guru.

Comment: I agreed that "the heart pumps blood" doesn't sound very old-fashioned (organs and components of a larger whole seem to be able to still use this pattern without sounding old-fashioned). The other two sentences do. A resource teaching English needs to explain that this usage exists, because people will come across it in older media (and specific instances where the usage continues), even if it is not current in speech

Answer (score -1):

"*a* male pheasant" is a somewhat colloquial way of referring to the species and "*the* male pheasant" is a somewhat formal way of doing the same.

In conversation, "a" would be perfectly idiomatic :

> A Sheltie is a herding dog.

and in a more formal context, let's say "expert" commentary on a televised national dog show, you'd probably hear this:

> The Sheltie is a herding breed.

Comment: For those of you who get your rocks off anonymously downvoting answers, consider that someone took time to compose an answer, and you come along and in a half a second make it look as though the answer is seriously flawed without even a word to say what you found wrong.

Answer (score -2):

**"The"** one is used when you are describing a male you have already mentioned before. In other words, you use **"the"** when you are sure the readers know which male you are actually talking about. Readers would think of this:
the male you said before......

Whereas **"a"** is used when you are describing a new idea to the reader. Readers would think of this when seeing the second sentence you provide:
there is a male pheasant which is brightly colored...
Then the readers get to know a new character: male pheasant➡️brightly colored.

Comment: There is no need for previous description when it is used for a category of animal or object. The lion is a noble beast. The electric car does not harm the environment.

Comment: This is true of articles in general, but not relevant to this particular question.